# Unmute video using device volume buttons

Tags: javascript, html5-video, html5-audio, volume, mute

I am trying to unmuting the muted video by using device volume buttons (like instagram or whatsapp status)

This code is not working as I thought from my research:

```js
var video1 = document.getElementById('bgvideo');

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 38) {
    `Volume up key`
    if (video1.muted === true) {
      video1.muted = false;
      navigator.mediaSession.setVolume(1);
    } else {
      navigator.mediaSession.setVolume(navigator.mediaSession.volume + 0.1);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Firstly, I don't think this is possible as there's no events raised when the client device volume is changed. Secondly, what is the point of muting a video control when the volume is turned off...? It's already muted by the device anyway.